# Enumeration lookup in Java

Tags: java, enums, lookup

I'm not too familiar with Java and need some help with an enumeration lookup (I think that's what it's called?)  I have many years of C experience, so I know what I'm trying to accomplish using C, but I don't know the equivalent syntax or construct in Java.

I don't have a C environment on this computer, so the syntax might be off, but this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
typedef enum regions_t {
     REGION_CALIFORNIA,
     REGION_HAWAII,
     REGION_LOUISIANA,
     REGION_NUM_REGIONS
} regions_t;

typedef struct regionData_t {
    regions_t regionName;
    char_t[50] url;
    int32_t population;
 } regionData_t;

 regionData_t myRegions[REGION_NUM_REGIONS] {
     {REGION_CALIFORNIA, "http://http://california.gov/", 10123321},
     {REGION_HAWAII, "http://hawaii.gov", 5123321},
     {REGION_LOUISIANA, "http://louisiana.gov/", 8123321}
 }
```

This way, I can access, for example, the url data in this fashion, which is easy to read and easy to expand upon:

```
myRegions[REGION_HAWAII].url
```

How do I accomplish the same idea in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
public enum Region {
    CALIFORNIA, HAWAII, LOUISIANA
}

public class RegionData {
    public final Region region;
    public final String url;
    public final int population;
    public RegionData(Region region, String url, int population) {
        this.region = region;
        this.url = url;
        this.popuplation = population;
    }
}

…

Map<Region, RegionData> regionData = new HashMap<Region, RegionData>();
regionData.put(Region.CALIFORNIA, new RegionData(Region.CALIFORNIA, "http://http://california.gov/", 10123321));
…

System.out.println(regionData.get(Region.CALIFORNIA).url);
```

But you can also use the fact that enums in Java are normal classes, too.

```
public enum Region {
    CALIFORNIA("http://http://california.gov/", 10123321),
    HAWAII("http://hawaii.gov", 5123321),
    LOUISIANA("http://louisiana.gov/", 8123321);
    public final String url;
    public final int population;
    private Region(String url, int population) {
        this.url = url;
        this.population;
    }
}

…

System.out.println(Region.CALIFORNIA.url);
```

Comment: Accepted, as it duplicates the functionality I was looking for closest.  Thanks.

Comment: You should use an EnumMap instead of HashMap in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need something like this:

```
public enum Region {
    CALIFORNIA("california-url", 1),
    HAWAII("hawaii-url", 2),
    LOUISIANA("louisiana-url", 3);

    private String url;
    private int population;

    private Region(String url, int population) {
        this.url = url;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public String url() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Notice that the String url should probably come from an external resource.

Comment: Note, in Java, enum members are objects, and as such can contain properties.  Which is to say, you can say `Region.CALIFORNIA.url()` (or even `Region r = Region.CALIFORNIA; String url = r.url();` rather than having to have a map of enums to properties if you use this method.   +1

Answer (score 0):

Java has enums also with slightly different syntax, but instead of a struct you'll want to encapsulate all of this information in a class. I am listing as direct of a translation as I can:

```
public enum Region
{
    REGION_CALIFORNIA,
    REGION_HAWAII,
    REGION_LOUISIANA;
}

public class RegionData
{
   Region region;
   String url;
   int    population;

   public RegionData(Region region, String url, int population)
   {
      this.region     = region;
      this.url        = url;
      this.population = population;
   }
}
```

Then you would want to look into the HashMap of HashTable classes to get the lookup functionality you want:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Answer (score 0):

Enums in Java are actually Classes. So you can do whatever you like with them except a few things like object instantiation at runtime.